# Is a Host/Spider aware of which file was cracked?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun

I understand that if a decker cracks a file, the host is immediately notified as it's a successful attack action. My question is: Is the host aware of which file was cracked?

The scenario is that we are attempting to spy on a resident of a relatively high-security hotel. As part of the legwork our decker got into the host and editted the file to add the group's name into the guest ledger. After the crack action, the host is aware that there was an attack, but is it (or the designated on-site Spider) aware of what was attacked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they need to search for you to see what you're up to. See p234.

> If you succeed with an Attack action, your target
> becomes aware that it is under attack by another icon,
> but it doesn’t automatically spot you. It will most likely
> actively search for you on its next action, although it
> will almost always alert its owner to the attack and (if
> it’s a host) launch IC, depending on the owner’s preferences and the gamemaster’s judgment. If you fail
> with an Attack action, you are not noticed, because
> you failed to affect your opponent (though note the
> damage effects of rejected code coming back to you,
> Illegal Actions, p. 231)

In addition, they don't track you directly in the code. See p248.

> HOST CONVERGENCE
> GOD doesn’t track personas inside a host, but it still
> keeps tabs on the traffic to and from the host. This
> means your Overwatch Score doesn’t change when
> you enter a host, and it continues to accumulate while
> you’re in the host. If you’re in a host when you reach
> convergence, you’re not burned and dumped like you
> are out on the grid (Overwatch Score and Convergence, p. 231). Instead, the host gets three marks on
> you and starts deploying IC.
> If you leave a host after convergence, the grid’s
> demiGOD converges on you immediately. You’re better
> off just jacking out from the host

If they wanted to know what was up, they'd have left a data bomb in the file, or had a hacker use the snoop action on you to see what matrix traffic you had.

Of course, once you cause problems they'll release IC to beat you up and watch what you do, and patrol ICs could spot you being naughty. You should make sure you're not being watched when you do your business.